# prefixQuery in Elastic search not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "timeout": "10m",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "input.custom_attrs.index": {
                                "value": "1",
                                "boost": 1
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "prefix": {
                              "input.custom_attrs.value": {
                                "value": "An*",
                                "boost": 1
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation -
I want to search the field with "An" as prefix .
Also i am sure that there is data with value "Annual" and "Annual Fund" ,which should appears in all match search .
But these records are not appearing with prefix query as given above.I tried with regexp query and wildcard query too .But they are also not working .Please give your valuable suggestions how to make the query working.

Comment: its been really long, would be great if you can upvote and accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

**Possible causes why it's not working**

look like while indexing data you used the default mapping or text field, which uses the [default standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which converts the generated tokens to lowercase.

While [prefix queries are not analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) and search term doesn't go through any analyzer and will not be lowercased.

In your case, you are searching for `An`, note capital `A`, while for `Annual` and `Annual fund`, tokens would be `annual` and `annual` and `fund`, hence its not matching.

**Solution:**

**Please use `an` as your prefix query and you should get your search results.**

Comment: Opster Elasticsearch Ninja , still it did not worked out.

Comment: It worked with regexpquery with .* concatenated with search string .  In above query i replaced the prefix json node with the below json element.                 
        "regexp": {
                              "input.custom_attrs.value": {
                                "value": "An.*",
                                "flags_value": 65535,
                                "max_determinized_states": 10000,
                                "boost": 1
                              }
                            }

Comment: @shantamohapatra, would not suggest regex queries as it could be very expensive, if you can provide your mapping and sample docs, I can further troubleshoot and make prefix query to return results